# How do I map a key into the shift key in Windows? (see picture of Canadian French keyboard)

Tags: keyboard-layout

As luck would have it, my computer dealer shipped me a laptop with a [Canadian French keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Canadian_French_.28Quebec.29)

[image: Canadian French keyboard layout]

instead of a US keyboard

[image: US keyboard layout]

Instead of saying how much Canadians from sea to sea hate this keyboard layout and hate being transitioned into it in the last couple of years, I'd like to ask for a software solution.  Is there a software that can map the [>>/<<] key to [Shift] and the [> < }] to [Enter], et cetera?

+1 if you can suggest how to type the "\".

-1 if you suggest, 'Just order a US keyboard. Replacing it takes a minute.' :)

Comment: What happens if you simply tell your computer that it's an en-us keyboard instead of fr-ca? I don't know how to do this on Windows, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know why manufactures insist on this new design for Canadian laptops. Always order mine from the US because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check out the [question](https://superuser.com/questions/282047/change-tilde-key-to-j-key-using-scancode-map) I asked earlier about key mapping. I put up a tut there for how to assign keys using the registry and another user, Yosh, put a link to some software that will do this for you.

I've never tried this on a french keyboard before but if you decide to do it manually, this hex key should map '\' to alt+1

```
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,3,00,00,00,2B,00,78,00,78,00,2B,00,00,00,00,00
```