# How to emulate PrintScreen key in VirtualBox on a Mac host

Tags: windows-7, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, virtualbox

I'm running VirtualBox on a Mac, using OS-X as the host and Windows 7 as the guest SO. I need to capture a screenshot in Win7 using PrintScreen or ALT+PrintScreen combination. How do I emulate PrintScreen key on Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the onscreen keyboard, or a third party app like [greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)(free) or you can use [scancodes](https://superuser.com/questions/282047/change-tilde-key-to-j-key-using-scancode-map).

Answer (score 0):

Have been struggling with this since some time on my Mac with a citrix client opening my work Windows machine.

Finally figured a solution that works for apps like Snagit.

Open the settings/preferences of the screen-capture app (in my case Snagit), and change the hotkey.

I changed it to F1. You can use any hotkey of your choice.

And now the print-screen works marvellously on my Windows remote desktop from my Macbook.