# How to add keyboard shortcut to press a specific key?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using a *Windows 10* OS, and I want to remap <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to emulate pressing <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See also: [Map Caps Lock to Control in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/949385/150988), [Can I switch the Alt and Ctrl keys on my keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/1190329/150988) and [Change tilde key to “j” key using Scancode Map](https://superuser.com/q/282047/150988).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to listen for the key pattern that you'd like, then execute the keystroke, ::{break} that you're interested in.

However, it might be easier to see if there's an [existing alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key#Keyboards_without_Break_key).